# windows form application c# submit a form using post method & get values after submission

Tags: c#, json

I want to submit a form to with 4 parameters using post method

my code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var postData = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            postData.Add("a", a);
            postData.Add("b",b);
            postData.Add("c",c);
            postData.Add("d",d);
            byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://ghjjhelper.com/checking.php", "POST",postData);
            var responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            tb1.Text= responsebody;              
        }
```

after my submission it return json:

```
{"response":[{"FName":"Jim","LName":"Jackson","ID":"123","mark":"60"}]};
```

how can i get above 4 values from this json after submission?

thx!!!

Comment: Do you mean "How can I read JSON in C#?"? Am I right in saying that your submission works and you receive the data indicated in response?

Comment: Pick any one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bjson%5D+parse

Comment: @DanielC,yes!read json after submitting form using post method